PyOWM can't parse the json it produces
I'm trying to use the json representation of pyowm objects. I realized something was off when I was converting to json and from json. I'm trying to re-create API-retrieved objects for testing without calling the API too many times.
I can summarize the issue with this line of code:
import pyowm
from pyowm.weatherapi25 import observation, location

owm = pyowm.OWM(API_KEY)
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
obs = mgr.weather_at_place(CITY)
observation.Observation.from_dict(obs.to_dict())

The result is
<...>
observation.Observation.from_dict(obs.to_dict())
  File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyowm/weatherapi25/observation.py", line 82, in from_dict
    raise exceptions.ParseAPIResponseError(
pyowm.commons.exceptions.ParseAPIResponseError: pyowm.weatherapi25.observation: impossible to read location info from JSON data

For reference, I have this pyowm version
$ pip freeze | grep pyowm
pyowm==3.3.0

Expected pyowm to be able to interpret the json it produced
